# Cannot create a new db instance on IBM cloud

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

I'm attending a MOOC course and I am a complete newbe of IBM cloud. The reason for which I am writing here is, as reported on the subject, that I am struggling with an istance creation.

First of all the system believes that converting part of the web pages in Italian is of any help to me, but it's not! In fact, all the times I'm googling for an help I have to figure out the English translation of what's written in Italian. This also means that, up to the moment in which I'll figure out how to convert ALL in English, some of the words could be a bit wrong.

By the way..

```
login into my IBM cloud account
--> click on catalogue
--> select "Services"
--> select "Database"
--> select the square "dB2"
```

A page like the following one opens to me

[image]

Here some problems:

The systems wants to know which is my location ("ubicazione") than, according with my MOOC explanations, I should have to select the socalled "lite plane", which is free. But the only way to select that "lite plane" is not to select "Milan" into the "ubicazione" selector.

So, once I've chosen "London", the "lite plane" square open up, as you can see in the following picture

[image]

But still there is no way to create a new istance as, in some ways, the system believes I already have a free instance opened

[image]

Particularly, in the previous image you can see the following message

```
Crea servizio

You can only have one instance of a Lite plan per service. To create a new instance, either delete your existing Lite plan instance or select a paid plan.
ID transazione: 4b9c59b60dd2413b8ba0e5ab1e5d5811
```

apart the weird fact that is half in Italian half in English, I realize that I may have a new instance opened in one of my previous attempts, but it is not, as you can see here

[image]

So, what's wrong in all of this? Could you help me to figure out how to create a new dB2 instance and how to make IBM working in English for ALL it's website?

Comment: You are showing "Monitoraggio" with no instance, but want to have Db2, right? Check under "Resources" (risorse?) by utilizing the menu button on the upper left. The Lite plan for Db2 on Cloud is only available in Dallas and London (and maybe Frankfurt)

Comment: There is no "risorse" or "resources" in any menu there

Comment: https://cloud.ibm.com/resources ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Db2 on Cloud offers the free lite plan only in Dallas and London](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Db2onCloud?topic=Db2onCloud-free_plan). If you get an error message that you already have such a service instance in your account, [check your existing resources](https://cloud.ibm.com/resources). If an instance exists use that one or delete it.